# "fitToSuppliedMarkers" not working in react native maps - android

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps-markers, react-native-maps

`I dont get any error message , but the map should be zoomed out automatically when i set my destination marker. However, the maps remains the same. And i have to view the directions from origin to destination, i have to do it manually.

i tried all possible solutions that were already available on stack overflow and the web, reduced my react native maps version to 0.31.1 but i wasnt successful in solving the issue.**your text**

This is my Map.js where i implemented the fitToSuppliedMarkers

```
`import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { SelectDestination, SelectOrigin } from '../Slices/navSlice';
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';
import { GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY } from '@env';
import Tw from 'twrnc';

const Map = () => {
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  const origin = useSelector(SelectOrigin);
  const destination = useSelector(SelectDestination);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!origin || !destination || !mapRef.current) return;

    // console.log(mapRef);
    // Zoom and fit to current markers
    mapRef.current.fitToSuppliedMarkers(["Origin", "Destination"], {
      edgePadding: { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50 },
      animated: true,
    });
  }, [origin, destination]);

  return (
    <MapView
      ref={mapRef}
      style={Tw`flex-1`}
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: origin?.location?.lat || 0,
        longitude: origin?.location?.lng || 0,
        latitudeDelta: 0.05,
        longitudeDelta: 0.05,
      }}
    >
      {origin && destination && (
        <MapViewDirections
          origin={origin.description}
          destination={destination.description}
          apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
          strokeWidth={3}
          strokeColor='black'
        />
      )}

      {origin?.location && (
        <Marker
          coordinate={{
            latitude: origin.location.lat,
            longitude: origin.location.lng,
          }}
          title="Origin"
          description={origin.description}
        />
      )}

      {destination?.location && (
        <Marker
          coordinate={{
            latitude: destination.location.lat,
            longitude: destination.location.lng,
          }}
          title="Destination"
          description={destination.description}
        />
      )}
    </MapView>
  );
};

export default Map;`
```

```
This is my package.json
{
  "name": "route-rover-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@sanity/client": "^6.4.4",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.2",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.10",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "twrnc": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Note : Origin and Destination values are perfectly set, even the map reference is working but the "fitToSuppliedMarkers" is still not working .

Comment: In addition, initially when the coordinates are set it does'nt zoom out, however when i remove one letter of origin in fitToSuppliedMarkers, ;basically making the expo app to refresh it zooms out on the very same code. I dont get it

Comment: but instead of using `fitToSuppliedMarkers` you can use `fitToCoordinates` its working fine

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the android operating system. To solve this problem I made setTimeout so that fitToSuppliedMarkers waits until the data is loaded into the destination and new markers are created. This is because if the map component is fetching data or redrawing markers when the destination changes, it may not have completed these operations by the time fitToSuppliedMarkers is called. I am not sure if setTimeout is a good solution, but at least it worked for me.

```
const mapRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!origin || !destination || !mapRef.current) return;

    setTimeout(() => {
      mapRef.current.fitToSuppliedMarkers(["origin", "destination"], {
        edgePadding: {
          top: 150,
          right: 50,
          bottom: 50,
          left: 50,
        },
      });
    }, 1500);
  }, [origin, destination, mapRef]);
```

Additionally, it is important to use only "identifier" property from the Marker component for fitToSuppliedMarkers function. So you need to specify "identifier" in the Marker component and set it to the fitToSuppliedMarkers array like this:

```
{origin?.location && (
        <Marker
          coordinate={{
            latitude: origin.location.lat,
            longitude: origin.location.lng,
          }}
          title="Origin"
          description={origin.description}
          identifier={"origin"}  // HERE identifier
        />
      )}

      {destination?.location && (
        <Marker
          coordinate={{
            latitude: destination.location.lat,
            longitude: destination.location.lng,
          }}
          title="Destination"
          description={destination.description}
          identifier={"destination"}  // HERE identifier
        />
      )}
```

And then you can use identifiers in your fitToSuppliedMarkers function.

```
mapRef.current.fitToSuppliedMarkers(["origin", "destination"], { //options })
```

The final working code for me looks like this

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectDestination, selectOrigin } from "../slices/navSlice";
import MapViewDirections from "react-native-maps-directions";
import { GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY } from "@env";

const Map = () => {
  const origin = useSelector(selectOrigin);
  const destination = useSelector(selectDestination);
  const mapRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!origin || !destination || !mapRef.current) return;

    setTimeout(() => {
      mapRef.current.fitToSuppliedMarkers(["origin", "destination"], {
        edgePadding: {
          top: 150,
          right: 50,
          bottom: 50,
          left: 50,
        },
      });
    }, 1500);
  }, [origin, destination, mapRef]);

  return (
    <MapView
      ref={mapRef}
      className="flex-1"
      mapType="mutedStandard"
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: origin.location.lat,
        longitude: origin.location.lng,
        latitudeDelta: 0.005,
        longitudeDelta: 0.005,
      }}
    >
      {origin && destination && (
        <MapViewDirections
          origin={origin.description}
          destination={destination.description}
          apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
          strokeWidth={3}
          strokeColor="black"
        />
      )}

      {origin?.location && (
        <Marker
          coordinate={{
            latitude: origin.location.lat,
            longitude: origin.location.lng,
          }}
          title="Origin"
          description={origin.description}
          identifier={"origin"}
        />
      )}

      {destination?.location && (
        <Marker
          coordinate={{
            latitude: destination.location.lat,
            longitude: destination.location.lng,
          }}
          title="Destination"
          description={destination.description}
          identifier={"destination"}
        />
      )}
    </MapView>
  );
};

export default Map;
```